# Form with disabled select option selected as default not sending anything to validate

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a form like so:

```
<select name="employment">
    <option disabled="" selected="">-- What is your employment status --</option>
    <option value="employed">Employed</option>
    <option value="self_employed">Self Employed</option>
</select>
```

In PHP I am running through each of the $_POST variables and then checking if they have a value. If not I then add that field to the array for an error message.

The issue is that if I leave the default 'disabled' message selected nothing is passed through a post value so theres nothing for me to validate.

If I print_r my $_POST variable then it contains no 'employment' field unless I select an option.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `<option disabled="" selected="" value ="">-- What is your employment status --</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="employment">
    <option disabled selected>-- What is your employment status --</option>
    <option value="employed">Employed</option>
    <option value="self_employed">Self Employed</option>
</select>
```

**disabled attribute**

1. The disabled attribute is a boolean attribute.
2. When present, it specifies that an option should be disabled
3. A disabled option is unusable and un-clickable.

**Syntax:**

```
<select disabled>
```

Not

```
<select disabled="">
```

In case of XHTML, syntax differs like

```
<select disabled="disabled">
```

**hidden attribute**

So, If you want to validate it. Use `hidden` in option.

```
<select name="employment">
    <option hidden>-- What is your employment status --</option>
    <option value="employed">Employed</option>
    <option value="self_employed">Self Employed</option>
</select>
```

When, nothing got selected, then it will output as `-- What is your employment status --`

```
<?php
echo $Employment=$_POST['employment'];
?>
```

**Output:** `-- What is your employment status --`

So, Now you can easily use your validation in dropdown

For more info, click [disabled attribute - W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_disabled.asp)

Comment: Amazing thanks! Didn't know about the hidden method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <select name="employment">
        <option disabled="" selected="" value ="">-- What is your employment status --</option>
        <option value="employed">Employed</option>
        <option value="self_employed">Self Employed</option>
    </select>
```

PHP:

```
if(empty($_POST['employment'])){
  return false;
}else {
  // I got value;
}
```